# How can I edit pg_hba.conf programmatically?

Tags: bash, postgresql, ubuntu, pg-hba.conf

I'm looking for a way to edit `pg_hba.conf` programmatically, similar to how `pg_conftool` allows you to edit `postgresql.conf`:

```
~$ pg_conftool 11 main set timezone 'UTC'
```

I tried using `pg_conftool` to edit `pg_hba.conf`. Unfortunately, it only allows `key = value` entries to be added / removed, which is not the format `pg_hba.conf` expects.

I can use `echo` and `sed` to achieve what I want, but I'm wondering if there's a better way. I found a tool `pg_hba` in `postgresql-common` that seems to be what I'm looking for:

https://salsa.debian.org/postgresql/postgresql-common

https://salsa.debian.org/postgresql/postgresql-common/blob/master/pg_hba

I have `postgresql-common` version `201.pgdg18.04+1` installed, however, I can't figure out how to access / install / invoke `pg_hba`.

Is the `pg_hba` tool the right tool for the job? If yes, how do I "install" the `pg_hba` binary for Ubuntu? If no, is there another recommended approach for programmatically editing `pg_hba.conf`?

Comment: It just so happens, someone blogged about that: https://blog.dbi-services.com/modifying-pg_hba-conf-from-inside-postgresql/

Answer (score 4):

We don't have a good way for editing pg_hba.conf yet. The pg_hba binary you found is still a WIP. If it works for you, please tell us, and we can work out if installing it to /usr/bin makes sense.

What works now is "pg_conftool 11 main pg_hba.conf edit", but that will just give you an editor.

Another option might be http://augeas.net/, it has a Pg_Hba "lens". (Puppet supports that natively.)